# MongoDB aggregate query how to split the array element

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In my mongodb, i have few collections, i want to create a new collection by comparing the collection 1 and collection 2 using pymongo.

```
Collection 1 :
Object id       timestamp                          Prof_Name   SUBJECT
abc67478898k  ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   ABDC      "sub1, sub2, sub3"
jjjjjjjjjj    ISODate("2018-01-03T09:26:37.541Z")   XYZ       "sub2, sub4, sub8"

Collection 2 :
Object id   timestamp               UUID   SUBJECT_ID            rating score
3333333    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7897  "sub1,sub4, sub7"     7      10
444444     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  4532   "sub2"               4      6
777777     ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")  7876  "sub1,sub2,sub3"      8      8
1111111    ISODate("2018-01-03TZ")   654   "sub1,sub3"          7      8
```

Json is as below :

```
data1 :
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc44"), "Prof_Name" : "Jack", "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT" : ["Maths", "Chemistry", "Machinery1", "Ele1"] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc45"), "Prof_Name" : "Mac", "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT" : ["Chemistry", "CS", "German"] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc46"), "Prof_Name" : "Bill", "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT" : ["German"] }

data2 :
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc46"), "Rating" : 6, "UUID" : 8123, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Maths", "ID" : "OI-123" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("7a563a5a5560fd08da86dc47"), "Rating" : 7, "UUID" : 8123, "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-10T16:08:26.613Z"), "SUBJECT_ID" : "Machinery1, Maths, French, German", "ID" : "OI-98" }
```

I'm trying to generate 3rd collection, where for each subject by Prof_name find matching subjects in collection2 and the UUID and UUID_count between a certain timestamp and my mongo query is as below:

```
db.data1.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"data2",
    "let":{"subject":{"$split":["$SUBJECT",", "]}},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match": {"expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":[{"$year":"$timestamp"}, 2016]}, {"$eq":[{"$month":"$timestamp"}, 1]}]}}},
      {"$addFields":{"SUBJECT_ID":{"$split":["$SUBJECT_ID",", "]},"SUBJECT":"$$subject"}},
      {"$unwind":"$SUBJECT"},
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$in":["$SUBJECT","$SUBJECT_ID"]}}},
      {"$facet":{
        "UUID":[{"$group":{"_id":{"id":"$_id","UUID":"$UUID"}}},{"$count":"UUID_Count"}],
        "REST":[
          {"$group":{"_id":null,"subjects_list":{"$addToSet":"$SUBJECT"},"UUID_distinct_list":{"$addToSet":"$UUID"}}},
          {"$addFields":{"subject_count":{"$size":"$subjects_list"},"UUID_distinct_count":{"$size":"$UUID_distinct_list"}}},
          {"$project":{"_id":0}}
         ]
      }},
      {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$mergeObjects":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$UUID",0]},{"$arrayElemAt":["$REST",0]}]}}}
    ],
    "as":"ref_data"
  }},
  {"$unwind":{"path":"$ref_data","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
  {"$addFields":{"ref_data.Prof_Name":"$Prof_Name"}},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$ref_data"}},
  {"$out":"data3"}
])
```

The abov query works fine if the SUBJECT is a string as :

```
SUBJECT
"sub1, sub2, sub3"
"sub2, sub4, sub8"
```

**My question is :** How do I change the query if  the SUBJECT column as an array of elements. Example as below :

```
subjects1
["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
["sub2", "sub4", "sub8"]
```

If I try the same query i get an error something like , split on string  found an array.

Comment: the above json is the most confusing i have seen in a while

Comment: You should consider to show us the sample data in JSON format instead of "table". Also it's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the json as well .

Comment: Try changing all the occurrences of split expression with array reference. for ex `"let":{"subject":{"$split":["$SUBJECT",", "]}}` can be `"let":{"subject":"$SUBJECT"}`

Comment: @Veeram Thank you !! i was looking for this !

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to use

```
> new Array("sub1, sub2, sub3")
```

[ "sub1, sub2, sub3" ]

my console ss

[image]